# Variable not set correctly by if statement in Python tkinter function

Tags: python, function, if-statement, python-3.x, tkinter

The code below is to calculate the points for a card game scorer I'm working on.  My question has to do with the if/elif statement inside my Round_Points function.  Whenever I run the code, Trick_Base is only set to 878 (just a random number I chose to test) from the final else statement, even when I enter a value between 6 and 10 for Tricks_Bid in the GUI (I'm using tkinter in Python 3.4).  Do I need to add something to make sure Trick_Base is set to the appropriate value from the if statement?  Or could there be something off in my entry widget?  Nothing I've searched so far has given me any clue as to what is wrong.  Thanks in advance for any help or suggestions!

PS: I based my code off of this example calculator: http://www.tkdocs.com/tutorial/firstexample.html
The problems started coming when I began to add in the if and elif statements.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

def Round_Points():
    if Tricks_Bid == 10:
        Trick_Base = 400
    elif Tricks_Bid == 9:
        Trick_Base = 300
    elif Tricks_Bid == 8:
        Trick_Base= 200   
    elif Tricks_Bid == 7:
        Trick_Base = 100    
    elif Tricks_Bid == 6:
        Trick_Base = 90   
    else:
        Trick_Base=878

    global Suit_Base

    Points.set(Trick_Base+Suit_Base)

root = Tk()
root.title("Tricks")

mainframe = ttk.Frame(root, padding="3 3 12 12")
mainframe.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=(N, W, E, S))
mainframe.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
mainframe.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)

Points = IntVar()
Suit_Base = 80
Tricks_Bid=IntVar()
Trick_Base=IntVar()

Tricks_Bid = ttk.Entry(mainframe, width=7, textvariable=Tricks_Bid)
Tricks_Bid.grid(column=2, row=1, sticky=(W, E))

ttk.Label(mainframe, textvariable=Points).grid(column=2, row=2, sticky=(W, E))
ttk.Button(mainframe, text="Calculate", command=Round_Points).grid(column=3, row=3, sticky=W)

ttk.Label(mainframe, text="Tricks").grid(column=3, row=1, sticky=W)
#ttk.Label(mainframe, text="is equivalent to").grid(column=1, row=2, sticky=E)
ttk.Label(mainframe, text="Points").grid(column=3, row=2, sticky=W)

for child in mainframe.winfo_children(): child.grid_configure(padx=5, pady=5)

Tricks_Bid.focus()
root.bind('<Return>', Round_Points)

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 5):

Two problems.

#### Problem one:

You first assign an `IntVar` to `Tricks_Bid`, then you overwrite that by assigning an `Entry` to `Tricks_Bid`.

#### Solution:

Rename all the cases where you are trying to refer to the `IntVar` something like `Tricks_Bid_Var`.

#### Problem two:

In `Round_Points`, You are attempting to compare an `IntVar` and an integer with the `==` operator.  That will not give you the result you are expecting.  An integer will never be `==` to an `IntVar`.  You need to call the `get` function to get the integer value contained within the `IntVar`.

#### Solution:

Instead of

```
  if Tricks_Bid_Var == 10:
        Trick_Base = 400
```

do this:

```
  if Tricks_Bid_Var.get() == 10:
        Trick_Base = 400
```